# How to tell when a transfer is complete with libssh2?

Tags: c, scp, libssh2

I'm using libssh2 for scp file transfer which in general is working. However, I'm currently trying to read some file from a weird SSH server which doesn't support to retrieve the meta data of the file upfront. Thus I don't know how big the file really is that I want to download.

I found out that libssh2 is putting a null byte at the end of the received data if the data is complete, which is ok for text files, but will fail or lead to incertainties for binary data which itself may contain a byte 0x00.

Assume this code:

```
LIBSSH2_CHANNEL* ch = libssh2_scp_recv2(session, remote_file_path, NULL);

ssize_t bytes_received = 0;
bool eof_received = false;
if (ch) {
    do {
        char buf[1024] = {0};
        bytes_received = libssh2_channel_read(ch, buf, sizeof(buf));

        eof_received = (buf[bytes_received - 1] == 0x00));
        printf("Received %d bytes.\n", bytes_received);
    } while (bytes_received > 0 && !eof_received);
}
```

If I transfer a binary file > 1024 bytes and by coincidence the 1024th byte of the file is 0x00, the code above will think EOF is reached and stop the transfer.
I also tested `libssh2_channel_eof` but this always gives false.

So, how can we properly know when a file is completely downloaded via SCP without knowing the expected filesize upfront?

Comment: https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_channel_eof.html maybe?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I already tried that, the eof flag is not set in my case, so libssh2_channel_eof always returns false.

Comment: What happens if you keep reading from the channel? Does the broken device eventually close the connection on you?

Comment: "I found out that libssh2 is putting a null byte at the end of the received data if the data is complete": this seems incredibly unlikely. More likely it returns `bytes_received` as zero or -1 at end of stream.

Comment: And your code is [tag:c], not [tag:c++].

Comment: If not, I fear your options are to use a ridiculously large buffer size (not a power of two) and hope it never returns a full buffer at EOF.

Comment: The scp protocol requires the sender to send the file size before sending the file contents. The receiver is supposed to use the file size to read the correct amount of data. Did you try passing a `libssh2_struct_stat` into `libssh2_scp_recv2()`? What file size is being filled in? What happens if you try retrieving a file from this server using the `scp` command-line utility?

Comment: @Kenster If I pass `libssh2_struct_stat` to `libssh2_scp_recv2()` libssh2 issues the `scp -p` command on the server which is indeed the unsupported command and thus the connection is closed.
Also I can see that the filesize is actually transfered in the C command `C0644 1023 data.bin` but it seems like libssh2 doesn't take that into account.

Comment: @Botje If I keep reading the read request eventually times out.

Comment: @Kenster My previous comment is not entirely correct, the C command is not ignored actually that's where libssh2 gets the filesize from. If I provide a stat struct, though, it add `-p` to the arguments to the server command.
The expected filesize also seems to be published in `session->scpRecv_size`.

Comment: Accessing `buf[bytes_received - 1]` will be out of bounds if `bytes_received` is zero or negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the libssh2 LIBSSH2_SESSION struct has [some fields](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/573e4ed0c9c3a6495566e238c42f2385c58240f8/src/libssh2_priv.h#L885) used for scp receive operations. While receiving a file, the field `session->scpRecv_size` will contain the size of the file being transferred. There are other fields for the file's permissions and timestamps.

As you've indicated, passing a `libssh2_struct_stat*` to the `libssh2_scp_recv2()` call causes the scp receive logic to include the "-p" option in the remote `scp` invocation. The stat struct is eventually populated from the fields of the session struct around [here](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/573e4ed0c9c3a6495566e238c42f2385c58240f8/src/scp.c#L762). If you don't want to send "-p" to the remote `scp` invocation, then you should pass `null` as the third argument to `libssh2_scp_recv2()`, and get the expected file size from `session->scpRecv_size`.

Comment: This works. It would be better if I could use some information from the public API, though.

Answer (score -1):

The official example of scp.c shows how to do it https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/example/scp.c#L152C17-L152C25 .

```
    channel = libssh2_scp_recv2(session, scppath, &fileinfo);
    while(got < fileinfo.st_size) {
        char mem[1024];
        int amount = sizeof(mem);
        ssize_t nread;

        if((fileinfo.st_size - got) < amount) {
            amount = (int)(fileinfo.st_size - got);
        }

        nread = libssh2_channel_read(channel, mem, amount);
        if(nread > 0) {
            write(1, mem, nread);
        }
        else if(nread < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "libssh2_channel_read() failed: %d\n",
                    (int)nread);
            break;
        }
        got += nread;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but this example relies on the filesize being known before starting the actual data transfer, so you can stop once you received all expected data.
In my case, I can't retrieve the filesize upfront as the `scp -p` command is not supported by the server.